# Selenium Firefox do not attach onClick event to submit button

Tags: java, jquery, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a for that with a submit button that looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right save_button" id="save_button" value="Save"/>
```

Using JQuery I attach a onclick event to popup a confirmation box:

```
$('body').on("click", ".save_button", function() {
        bootbox.confirm("Do you want these changes to be live in the website?", 
    function(result) {
                if(result) {
                    $("#editPageForm").parsley().validate();
                    if( $("#editPageForm").parsley().isValid()) {
                        $("#editPageForm").submit();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

When I test this step by hand everything works fine the form is validated and shows the confirmation box, and after pressing the OK button it saves the content as expect.

But if I use Selenium test I see all the steps going ok, but when the save button is pressed instead of firing this function it just submit the form.

This is the code used to create the driver:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
return new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Other Javascript code does work, but I am getting problems with this specific one.

I am using FF44 and selenium drivers I tried 2.48.2, 2.49.1, 2.50 and none of them worked

Did any of you experienced any similar issue?

Thanks

Comment: I can't see how JQuery gets loaded and the listeners attached, but I'd suggest your Driver is rushing to click the button before the listener has been added, bypassing your client-side validation. Can you ensure the page is fully loaded first? At least add a few seconds delay and then test.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the page hasn't fully rendered and therefore the click listener hasn't been registered yet. Adding a wait may solve your problem, something like:

```
    WebDriverWait buttonWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30L);
    buttonWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someButton")));
```

Comment: @AndrewRegan the step that is clicking the button is in the middle of the test, long after the page is loaded, so it is not a question of timing